# Dev c++ creates test.txt , when i create a txt file using FILE

Tags: c, file, ide

i have been practicing c in the emulator in my windows 10.
Later I switched to dev C++ IDE.
When I was working with FILE in C .
The file which is created gets a name test.txt , while I have given some other name.
kindly help through it.

Here is the code below :

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char buff[255];
    fp=fopen("text.txt","wr");
    fputs("one\ntwo\nthree\nfour",fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

All I am getting is test.txt for every different file name

Comment: I got it its because I use "wr" mode to open the file

Comment: this is the only statement in the OPs code that could create a file (assuming it does not already exist.)  `fp=fopen("text.txt","wr");`  Why would you expect any other file to be created?  Note: `fputs("one\ntwo\nthree\nfour",fp);` is only placing some text into the file.  Note: if the file already exists, the `w` of the mode operand will only truncate the file to 0 length.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about the opening mode, you can refer to @Amar Srivastava's answer on this stackoverflow question: [File opening modes in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043166/file-opening-modes-in-c)

edit: i know the post above is about c++ but the opening modes in c and c++ are really the same